# Regex to ignore variable initializations that have already been declared

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that would ignore a token if a part of the token has already been captured before.

**Example**

```
var bold, det, bold=6, sum, k
```

Here, `bold=6` should be ignored because `bold` has already been captured. 
Also, `var` must be present before any matching can take place, the last token `k` should not be followed by a comma. Only the variables within `var` and the last token `k` should be followed by a comma.

**Another Example**

```
var bold=6, det, bold, sum, k
```

Here, `bold` which follows `det` should be ignored because `bold=6` has already been captured.

i tried using this pattern `(?:\\bvar\\b|\\G)\\s*(\\w+)(?:,|$)`, but it doesn't ignore what has been repeated.

Comment: What do you mean by "part of the token has already been captured before"?  If you have `var a, ab` should you ignore `ab`?  Also, this problem is best not solved by a single regex.  I would capture all tokens into a list and then use some logic to discard the ones I don't want.

Comment: the part i mean, is initialization precisely. Eg var b, b=8. it would ignore the second b=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what information you need to get you can try with:

1. Solution working only in Java, will give you variable name and start
   and end idices:

   ```
   (?<=var.{0,999})(?<!=)(?!var\b)\b(?<var>\w+)\b(?<!var.{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999})
   ```

   [RegexPlanet Demo](http://fiddle.re/xbndj6)

   it uses ugly, but quite effective feature of Java regex: intervals
   (`x{min,max}`) in lookbehind. As long as you use interval with
   minimal and maximal length, you can use it in Java regex. So instead
   of `.*` you can use for example `.{0,999}`. It will fail if there
   need to be more char than 999, you can use bigger number, but I
   think it is not necessary in this cese. Named group `<var>` is optional here, you can replece it in code with normal group.

   Implementation in Java:

   ```
   public class Test{
       public static void main(String[] args){
           String test = "var bold, det, bold=6, sum, k\n" +
                   "var foo=6, abc, foo, xyz, k";
           Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=var.{0,999})(?<!=)(?!var)\\b(?<var>\\w+)\\b(?<!var.{1,999}(?=\\k<var>).{1,999}(?=\\k<var>).{1,999})").matcher(test);
           while(matcher.find()){
               System.out.println(matcher.group("var") + "," + matcher.start("var") + "," + matcher.end("var"));

           }

       }
   }
   ```

   with output (variable name, start index, end index):

   ```
   bold,4,8
   det,10,13
   sum,23,26
   k,28,29
   foo,34,37
   abc,41,44
   xyz,51,54
   k,56,57
   ```

Explanation of regex:

- `(?<=var.{0,999})` - must be preceded by text `var` followed by any
  number of characters, but not new line,
- `(?<!=)` - should not be preceded by equal sign, to avoid matching variable name and value as different matches,
- `(?!var\b)` - cannot be followed by `var` word, to avoid matching this word,
- `\b(?<var>\w+)\b` - separate word, captured into `<var>` group,
- `(?<!var.{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999})` - the matched word cannot by preceded by `var` word followed by some chars, including captured word, followed by some chars, inclusing captured  word again,

But as I wrote, it will work only in Java.

2. If you need just variable names, you can use:

   ```
   (?<=var\s|\G,\s)(?<var>\w+)(?=,|$)|(?<=var\s|\G,\s)(?<initialized>[^,\n]+)
   ```

   [DEMO](http://(?%3C=var%5Cs%7C%5CG,%5Cs)(?%3Cvar%3E%5Cw%20)(?=,%7C$)%7C(?%3C=var%5Cs%7C%5CG,%5Cs)(?%3Cinitialized%3E[%5E,%5Cn]%20))

   to get variable names without duplications. But if you want
   start/end indices, it will capture into group second occurence of
   duplicated variable name.

Comment: Thanks alot, almost what i was looking for. The first output was correct, but the second output doesn't match foo=6. It only matches foo. I want it to match `foo=6`, since foo=6 came before `foo`.

Comment: @james then try with `(?<=var.{0,999})(?<!=)(?!var\b)\b((?<var>\w+)[^,|\n]*)\b(?<!var.{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999})` it should give you right output [demo](http://fiddle.re/xbndj6).

Comment: Thanks a lot. works now. Tho, it still doesn't detect the last word k

Comment: @james sorry my mistake, it should be `(?<=var.{0,999})(?<!=)(?!var\b)\b((?<var>\w+)[^,|\n]*)\b(?<!var.{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999}(?=\k<var>).{1,999})` [demo](http://fiddle.re/xbndj6), I replaced `[^,|\n]+` with `[^,|\n]*`

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your regex to this with a negative lookahead:

```
(?:\bvar\b|\G)\s*(?:(\w+)(?!.*\b\1\b)(?:=\w+)?|\S+)(?:,|\bk\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uM5wR0/2)

Rather than keeping track of what it has already matched it will skip matching a word if it is followed in rest of the string.

Here `(?!.*\b\1\b)` is a **negative lookahead** that will avoid matching a word if same word is found on RHS of input. `\1` is back-reference of matched word.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?:\bvar\b|\G)        # match text var or \G
\s*                   # match 0 more spaces
(?:                   # start non-capturing group
   (\w+)(?!.*\b\1\b)  # match a word if same word is found in rest of the input
   (?:=\w+)?          # followed by optional = and some value
 |                    # regex alternation
   \S+                # OR match 1 or more non-space character
)                     # close non-capturing group
(?:,|\bk\b)           # match a comma or k
```

Comment: In your demo,  it didn't detect the last k.

Comment: It did detect `var` and last `k` that's why both `var` and `k` are not in matched groups.